# perforce: 'p4 changes' with its change 'diff' between two changesets

Tags: perforce

is there a way to list out all the changes with each change's subject and its change difference between two changesets?

```
p4 diff2 -u //depot/build/stage/gobuild/...@676277 //depot/build/stage/gobuild/...@676640
```

this giving only consolidated diff

Comment: `p4 diff2` gives you differences.

Comment: Thx @BryanPendleton p4 diff2 -u //depot/build/stage/...@676277 //depot/build/stage/...@676640 is giving consolidated diff whereas i wanted each diff with changeset subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to script Bartek's answer, in one easy line:

```
p4 -Ztag -F "describe %change%" changes -s submitted @676277,676640 | p4 -x - run
```

If you want to massage the output further you'll need to buckle down and learn a scripting language -- the p4 command line can do a lot on its own but it's no substitute for Perl.  :)

Comment: p4 -Ztag -F "describe -du %change%" changes //depot/build/stage/gobuild/...@676277,676640 -s submitted | p4 -x - run is perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

`p4 changes` won't show you diffs. You could use it for collecting changelist numbers and then you could call `p4 describe` for each which will produce a diff.

See `p4 help describe` for the formats of diffs.

Comment: Im not looking for 'p4 changes' cmd only .. any other way